# Using React Dev Tools with Preact

Tags: reactjs, webpack, preact

I have just got [`preact-redux-example`](https://github.com/developit/preact-redux-example) up and running, and now I am attempting to use Preact Dev Tools in my app.

Based on [this post](https://github.com/developit/preact/pull/339#issuecomment-252769393) I assumed it was a case of adding

```
import 'preact/devtools'
```

into the entry point (`app.js`) file.

However, this yields the following error:

```
./src/components/app.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'preact/devtools'
```

Is there something else I need to install, or am I on the wrong track?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`preact/devtools` has landed in version [6.4.0](https://github.com/developit/preact/releases/tag/6.4.0), but the example project uses version `4.8.0`. So you need to upgrade the preact version to be able to import it:

```
npm install --save preact@latest
```

Or if you're using [yarn](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn) you can run:

```
yarn upgrade preact
```

Comment: For people coming here using preact X, there's a pending PR to get the latest react dev tools working: https://github.com/preactjs/preact/pull/1549